# Conceptual multithreading with semaphores and pseudo random numbers

Tags: multithreading, random, semaphore

This is a very general question that is mostly just conceptual.  I was thinking about testing the random number generator to see its effectiveness at following a uniform distribution over some x values (ex 6 for a dice roll).  Doing this in a simple loop is how I have it now, but I was thinking about multithreading the simulation.

I was wondering if this would give me any speedup since I would only have one random number generator shared between all threads with semaphore protection (needed to ensure no two threads access and generate random numbers at the same time meaning duplication of results).

Since each thread would hardly have other operations (just if statements for checking and incrementing x) would threading it even give me faster results, or will the dependency on one random number generator mean it would be essentially the same as a single thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you should see an increase in performance, at least until the number of threads equals the number of cores in use.  However, in reality, you'll be adding code (and therefore execution time) to handle the multithreading infrastructure, and if the bulk of each thread's time is spent waiting for a slow RNG you may see a decrease in performance.

On the other hand, you may be able to improve performance with some cleverness.  For example, you might have one task dedicated to generating random numbers, and if you're only looking for values from 1 to 6, you may be able to generate more than one value from each result from the RNG.  You could put those values into a queue and let the other tasks read from the queue.  Of course, you'd have to be careful that your optimizations don't alter the distribution of the RNG.

Unless the idea of counting execution cycles excites you, the best way to find your answer is by trying it.  And it's always educational to use a profiler to find out where most of the time is spent--this is notoriously difficult for humans to get right through intuition alone, and even experienced developers are often surprised by the results.

Comment: Awesome suggestion with seperaring the rng from the processing of results.  Not entirely sure how I would use 1 rng to simulate multiple rolls without screwing with the distribution though.  I have never used a profiler and needed an excuse to start, I think ill use this as one, thanks.

Comment: Just a quick example:  if you're generating numbers from 1 to 6, you'll only need 3 bits for each number.  If your RNG generates 32-bit values, you can get 10 groups of 3 bits from each value.

Comment: I really doubt that you are going to see speed improvements with running the RNG in another thread.  The overhead in synchronizing a queue of random numbers would far outweigh any benefits.

Comment: @Gray - You may well be right.  All the more reason to try it, and to use a profiler.

Answer (score 5):

I think you've answered your own question.  Your plan will lead to a single-threaded use of the RNG, with different threads taking turns to be the single one in use.  You'll probably achieve a speedup, but only a negative one.

Comment: "achieve a speedup" really meaning "affect the speed"?  Speedup implies positive to me.

Answer (score 0):

> needed to ensure no two threads access and generate random numbers at
>   the same time

This mean that really only one worker thread would be run so you are not use benefits of multithreading. Or I've missed a point where you mentioned distributing some work across the multipel threads?

If you somehow improve overall design around RNG access from the multiple threads - consider using `ReaderWriterLock` technique rather than `Semaphore`.

Comment: I guess I thought there might be speedup to a certain extent because one thread would access rng then have to check and Inc the corresponding value.  While it was doing that, the other thread would be accessing rng.  Also, I'm curious abulout readereriterlock and his that might help, would generating the next number requirewriter access to the rng to update the seed value?  Definitely speaking out of my ass here.

Comment: I believe the solution depends on implementation of the RNG, are you using self made or built in? Which language/framework you are using for development?

Comment: At the moment I am just using the C# built in rng.